# Как полностью удалить python?

Tags: python

Если не ошибаюсь, то я удалил все что с ним связано, но когда захожу в консоль и пишу python, он выводит его версию)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я бы, кстати, не рекомендовал удалять все питоны из системы, бывают программы, которые им пользуются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно поиском найти файл python.exe

Или в командной строке дать команду path и поискать там змеюку...

Comment: Это заняло часа полтора, но в итоге помогло)

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Поможет найти установку.